# Save table to csv file where both file name and table name are variables

Tags: kdb

If I want to save table `table1` to csv file `/tmp/table1.csv` I can do it with:

```
`:/tmp/table1.csv 0: csv 0: table1
```

But what if both file name and table name come from string variables?

```
fname:"/tmp/table1.csv"
tname: "table1"
/ how do I save table tname to file fname?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
hsym[`$fname] 0: csv 0: value `$tname
```

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/filewords/#hsym

and valuing a symbol, returns the value of the variable it names.